# Relation between memory and creativity

Tags: cognitive-psychology, memory, reference-request, creativity

What theories exist explaining the interaction between creativity and long term memory? I am especially interested in how, in creative work, a thought triggers a memory that may not be related to it in an obvious way. I realise this is a broad question, so I was hoping you folks could give me a few articles or books as starting points.

Comment: Welcome to CogSci.SE Richard! This site is a little hard to navigate at first, so please let me give you some advice. First of all, narrowing down your question as much as possible is helpful. Maybe reduce your question to "what are the theories of the interaction between memory and creativity"? In the answers that will be provided, often a few articles and a book will be given, so there's no need to specify the need for a book.

Comment: I took the liberty of heavily editing your question. Let me know what you think and remember that you're always able to edit it further.

Comment: You may want to look into [loose association](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derailment_(thought_disorder)) and [lateral thinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_thinking) as these may be related to the suggested manner of thinking.